# How does Peer-to-Peer NTP resolve time variance?

Tags: ntp

If I have two servers set up with peer-to-peer NTP and both have different times, how do they decide what time to use?

Comment: Segal's law:  A man with a watch knows what time it is.  A man with two watches is never sure.

Comment: Careful with the term "Peer-to-Peer NTP", afaik it is not a well-defined concept in NTP, although an "NTP peer" is. Using PTP as peer-to-peer in the clock syncing world is very easily confused with the Precision Time Protocol (PTP), a more precise alternative for NTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since neither peer is an authority, they will both adjust their clocks to the midpoint of the difference between them.